# Sort and add elements of a list based on a common attribute

Tags: python, list

I have a csv file that has the data:

```
California  C1      A         1
.           .       .         .
.           .       .         .
.           .       .         .
.           .       .         .
```

so it looks like this when viewed in python:

```
['California','C1','A',1] 
['Hawaii','H1','B',2]
['California','C1','A',3]
['California','C2','A',4]
['Hawaii','H1','A',5]
['Hawaii','H1','A',6]
['California','C1','B',7]
['Hawaii','H2','B',8]
['California','C1',B',9]
['Hawaii','H2','A',10]
```

I wanted to have the output as top 1 of each list, as follows:

```
['California','C1',B',16]
['California','C2','A',4]
['Hawaii','H1','A',11]
['Hawaii','H2','A',10]
```

basically. I wanted to sum the last part of the list based on the first 3 attributes of the list then return the top 1 given the three attributes. My code are as follows:

```
import collections

def top_1(list):
    ranking = collections.Counter(list)
    return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(),key=lambda x:(‐x[1], x[0]))
    [:1]]
csvReader =csv.reader(open('data.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    data = []
    for i in range(int(line[3]):
       data.append([line[0], line[1], line[2]))
    print top_1(data)
```

but it does not give me the output that I am expecting.

Comment: is your data really like in your input or is that the parsed data as a list?

Comment: Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and try to provide an example that others can easily execute w/o having to reformat your data and your code.

Comment: Why are you using `return` before creating your *csvReader*?

Comment: @user3100115 sorry for the indexing, the return is part of the function I created.

Comment: @roadrunner66 apologies for the confusion and thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Kordi I edited my post, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: what is the output then

Comment: @KWeiss basically the output is the highest third attribute. For example:
 the total of the list containing  the first three attributes of 'California','C1' and 'A' is 4 while that of 'California','C1' and 'B' is 16, so the ['California','C1',A',4] is drop offed while the ['California','C1',B',16] is shown. same goes for Hawaii: ['Hawaii','H1','A',5] is greater than ['Hawaii','H1','B',2] so the former is shown...apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @TouyaD.Serdan It's a one liner with itertools.groupby I added my answer, skipped the csv read thing.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach should give you the desired output:

```
from collections import Counter    
from itertools import groupby, islice
import csv

counts = Counter()

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        counts.update({tuple(row[:3]) : int(row[3])})

output = []        
for k, g in groupby(sorted(counts.iteritems(), key=lambda x:(x[0][0], -x[1])), lambda x:x[0][0]):
    output.extend([list(e[0]) + [e[1]] for e in islice(g, 0, 2)])

print output
```

This will display:

```
[['California', 'C1', 'B', 16], ['California', 'C2', 'A', 4], ['Hawaii', 'H1', 'A', 11], ['Hawaii', 'H2', 'A', 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code

You can use itertools  groupby and csv read. Then it's just a two liner. Split the line into 4 lines for better readability.

```
import itertools
import operator
import csv

inputList = list(csv.reader(open('data.csv','rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar="'"))
groupedList = [x[0:3] + (sum(int(z[3]) for z in y),) for (x,y) in
               itertools.groupby(sorted(inputList, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2)),
                                    key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1, 2))]

print groupedList
```

**Explanation**

Read the csv and convert it into a list. Sort the list after the first 3 Columns, then group by after this first 3 columns. As return Value take the first 3 columns and then sum over the grouped result of the column 4 cast to int.

## Input data.csv

```
'California','C1','A',1
'Hawaii','H1','B',2
'California','C1','A',3
'California','C2','A',4
'Hawaii','H1','A',5
'Hawaii','H1','A',6
'California','C1','B',7
'Hawaii','H2','B',8
'California','C1','B',9
'Hawaii','H2','A',10
```

Note in your input there is a missing `'` in `'C1',B',9`

## Output

```
[('California', 'C1', 'A', 4), 
 ('California', 'C1', 'B', 16), 
 ('California', 'C2', 'A', 4), 
 ('Hawaii', 'H1', 'A', 11), 
 ('Hawaii', 'H1', 'B', 2), 
 ('Hawaii', 'H2', 'A', 10), 
 ('Hawaii', 'H2', 'B', 8)]
```

Comment: @DaoWen Thanks for the notice. Would never do this in my own code, but for the examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do, is sum the last column for each of the first three column's unique values.

Try this approach:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(int)

with open('somefile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        results[tuple(row[:-1])] += int(row[-1])

print(results)
```